# Есть ли способ в MongoDB изменить названия индексов при получении результатов запроса?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

В MongoDB по умолчанию индекс называется _id. А в моем приложении он называется id. И во всех местах, где я запрашиваю данные из базы, не хотелось бы каждый раз принудительно прописывать, мол, result.id = result._id, как-то это некрасиво выглядит.
Может быть, есть способ в параметрах запроса это как-нибудь указать?

Comment: Использовать оператор `$project` для манипулирования полями(переименовывать). 
`$project: { _id: 0,  id: "$_id"}`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает, но никак не получается объединить это с find(), может подскажете, в чем дело? Я так понимаю, что для поиска,например,`find({_id: "1"})` в случае с aggregate надо писать так, но этот вариант почему-то не работает: `db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: "1"}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, id: "$_id"}},
   ])`

Comment: Для того, чтобы искать по id, то его нужно преобразовать в тип ObjectID.

Comment: `const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
... { '$match': { '_id': new ObjectId(id) } },`

Comment: Если бы вы только исключали поля, то указывать остальные не нужно. Но так как вы определили новое поле, то нужно указать какие ещё включать.